# Is OK to place a div inside th tag?

Tags: html

I didn't think this was a problem but my IDE seems to tell me otherwise. Are there any browsers that would fail to render this correctly?

Using Netbeans IDE 7.3.

Thanks.

Comment: why did the answer with 5 upvotes just get deleted?

Comment: because was wrong along with the upvotes ;)

Comment: @iglo : yes, it's safe to place a `div` inside the `th` tag, see http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/divInsideTH_06dec13.html

Comment: Not sure why it got deleted. Wasn't it correct? I've never seen this cause any issue in any browser. Does any other IDE show syntax errors here too? Would be interesting to know.

Comment: JKF, that settles it for me, thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

According to the HTML5 specification, [that's absolutely fine](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-tr-element). The content model is a normative description of what is allowed to be a child/descendant of the element. For the `<th>` element, only the following tags are permitted:

> #### Content model:
>
> Flow content, but with no header, footer, sectioning content, or
>   heading content descendants, and if the th element is a sorting
>   interface th element, no interactive content descendants.

The `<div>` tag is an example of flow content, so this should validate.

In the future, I'd like to recommend the [W3C's validator service](https://validator.w3.org/), which gives you a quick check to see whether your HTML is valid. In this instance, it passes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>&nbsp;</title></head>
<body>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <div></div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Strange that it lists a `table` tag as acceptable.  You wouldn't put a `div` in a `table` tag directly, but you would put it inside a `td`, which isn't listed.  Unless I'm not understanding something correctly here.

Comment: the specifications says where and when is recommended to be used, it doesn't say this is incorrect

Comment: The question was is div ok inside th, not tr. Test putting it inside a th. you'll find that it's fine.

Comment: @SlyRaskal - You are misunderstanding the what the spec is saying about flow content. What it's saying is that table IS flow content, (e.g. that table is allowed as a child of div), not that it can have flow content children.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy - SlyRaskal was talking about the table element. You are correct. th is not flow content, but it allows flow content children. "content model" describes an element's allowed children and descendants.

Comment: @Alohci: sorry, I didn't read over your comment carefully -- thought it was directed to me.

Answer (score 4):

`<DIV>` inside `<TD>` or `<TH>` is absolutely fine, and is reasonably common requirement for positioning & layout purposes.

For example, the `TH` cannot have `position:relative` set, but the `DIV` can.. enabling it to be a positioning container.